# How can I transfer file via RDP-connection over PowerShell or CMD?

Tags: powershell, cmd, rdp

I need transfer file via RDP-connection over command line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you are RDPed on to a machine, you need to have the option to see the drives of your local machine on the remote machine turned on.
MSTSC -> Show Options -> Local Resources -> More -> Drives

Once you are RDPed on to the remote machine, you can treat copy from your local machine using, for example, the path "\tsclient\C\GitHub".

Comment: I had to use two forward slashes at the beginning of the path.   \\tsclient\

Answer (score -3):

You can copy a file without RDP or PowerShell using a UNC pathname.

```
COPY x.txt \\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME\Users\lit
```

Is there a reason that the file MUST be transferred via RDP?

Comment: This is using SMB/CIFS protocol and not RDP. One reason would be if the only allowed port is the RDP one (TCP 3389) not the multiple ones that are sometimes needed for a SMB/CIFS solution. This restricted configuration is quite common in the field.